# How to load my mobile web app in a webview from Facebook Android native app?

Tags: android, facebook, webview

I have a fully-working Facebook webapp that is accessible using mobile browser. When a link to the app is posted in Facebook wall I expect the native app to open it in a webview, but this behaviour is only working in the IOS native app.

When the link is clicked from de Android native app, the web browser is launched and my app is loaded but the user has to log on Facebook again.

I've readed Facebook documentation and all it says about this topic is this:

> **Web Apps loaded inside an iOS or Android Webview**
>
> The Javascript SDK is compatible web pages loaded inside webviews within in the native Facebook iOS or Android apps. When users follow links to web sites or web apps within the native Facebook app, they'll remain inside the native Facebook app experience, and will see the link they clicked on within a UIWebView (iOS) or WebView (Android).
>
> While webviews in native apps are normally sandboxed from the standard browser session, the Facebook app injects a session into the webview so that your social plugins and authentication still work as if they were being loaded in the default device browser's shared session space.
>
> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/gettingstarted/#webview

I've already implemented the auto-login features described here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/using-auto-login/

But without webview session data is not passed to the webapp.

Comment: is deep linking enabled in facebook app settings?

Comment: The app i am developing it's not an ios/android native app, it's a webapp so there is no depp linking in app settings.

Comment: @jocriaba Have you found any solution on this one? I have problem also integrating facebook login on my web apps. Based on my research, it only works if we are running it using `localhost` or html files are uploaded to web server. But I was not able to make it work when packed  as an app.

Comment: @JunM no solution yet. I'll update if I found one

Comment: We have got the same issues. On iOS everything works fine. Hell, even the whole facebook fanpage gets loaded into the native app's webview. **On Android 2.2 the native facebook app opens the browser** and on Android 4 the native facebook app loads about one minute and then redirects back to the origin page (maybe a time-out problem).